# How to output pure xml from a portlet?

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc, portlet

We are trying to output pure xml from a 286 portlet running on Websphere Portal Server 6.1 using the Spring 3.0 mvc framework.

We had the following at the top of the jsp:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" language="java" contentType="text/xml; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt"%>
```

If we just have xml elements in a jsp, the resultant page at the browser has the portal theme html around the xml.  Does anyone have a recommendation (with example snippets if at all possible) please?

Answer (score 0):

Portlets are page fragments; markup should match the surrounding theme. Serve your XML file as [a resource](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0803_hepper/0803_hepper.html#N100F9).

Comment: Yes they are only fragments...  I am afraid I forgot to mention an important point in my question...  We are trying to allow legacy systems to make parameter calls into the portlet.

The resource call, as you suggest, is correct for internal to the portlet calls but doesn't work from a legacy system that doesn't know or understand the portlet urls.

Comment: We have now solved the problem by using a 'friendly url' for the page and packaging a servlet inside the portlet war as described by cmelgar in [this link](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?44413-AbstractPdfView-from-a-Portlet)

Answer (score 0):

We have an answer we found by packaging a servlet in the war as mentioned in the comments above.  My original question didnt include an important piece of info... we were trying to output the xml after a call from a legacy system... so it cant use the portlet resource urls.